# Retrieve or refund stripe transactions by metadeta

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have searched for stripe apis and could not find if we can retrieve any transaction or refund it with only metadeta[order_id] present.

I get only order id from an external source and it is unique. External source declined to send charge id so only thing I have is metadeta.

I tried standard way to get the data but it says missing required charge. I used `\Stripe\Charge::retrieve`.

Please let me know if there is any other way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to search via the API by metadata, though you can do it via the Dashboard.

Alternatively, you can [list all Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#list_charges) and then search within those results, or if this is something you need to do a lot of going forward, you can store a map of `order_id => charge_id` in your database to make this a quick, local lookup.

Comment: I did that, I tried to retreive it like this 
`
$allcharges = \Stripe\Charge::all(array("limit" => 100));
foreach($allcharges->data as $item)
{
  if($item->metadata[order_id] == '1234567890'){
  echo $item->id;
  }
  
}` but it gets empty page

Comment: Does whatever you're searching for actually exist in the account?  I.e. if you search for that in the Dashboard, do you find it?

Comment: yes it does exist and i can find it in the stripe dashboard

Comment: Ok, then you'll just need to work through the logic of your filter until it works.  You probably also want to use Auto-Pagination to make sure you can review all, and not just the first 100: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#auto-pagination